# PIXI.js - How to draw a half of the circle?

Tags: pixi.js

I'm new to PIXI.js to make a game.
How can I draw a half of the circle like this without using image?

[image]

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Make sure you read [the official documentation](http://pixijs.download/dev/docs/PIXI.Graphics.html#arc) before you resort to stackoverflow. :)

Use the PIXI.Graphics class to draw shapes programmatically. It has an `arc` method for drawing arcs, curves, or parts of circles.

```
var semicircle = new PIXI.Graphics();
semicircle.beginFill(0xff0000);
semicircle.lineStyle(2, 0xffffff);
semicircle.arc(0, 0, 100, 0, Math.PI); // cx, cy, radius, startAngle, endAngle
semicircle.position = {x: sW/2, y: sH/2};
stage.addChild(semicircle);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/_jered/kydtg9jq/

Comment: @juniper- thanks, it seems the URL has changed. Updated the link.

Comment: here is how you can make any angles https://jsfiddle.net/0dhkp2z1/